# object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, telebot

появляется данная ошибка "object has no attribute 'message_handler'". скачал я всё правильно, но почему то появляется эта ошибка

```
import telebot

token = ''

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_type=['text'])

def command(message):
    if message == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет!')
    
    elif message.text.lower() == 'пока':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Пока, заходи ещё!')
    
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message)

bot.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Как назвался модуль который вы установили?

Comment: pip install telebot, потом pip instal pytelegrambotapi

Comment: эммм, а зачем `pip install telebot`? Из-за этого у вас и ошибка.

Comment: Удалите telebot

Comment: я удалил через команду pip uninstall telebot. теперь у меня выводит ошибку, что атрибут TekeBot не существует у telebot module ('telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot)

Comment: Удалите и pytelegrambotapi и потом заново установите